# Super-radiant amplification in electromagnetic perturbation in Kerr background

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, black-holes, perturbation-theory, kerr-metric

Let an electromagnetic field be scattered by a Kerr black-hole; then its amplitude will be amplified, but its frequency will remain same (super-radiant amplification). Hence though its intensity will be increased, its energy should not be changed (as its frequency remains same).

Still why the popular books like,

(i) Padmanabhan, T. (2010) Gravitation Foundation and Frontiers. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge.

(ii) Chandrasekhar, S. (1983). The Mathematical Theory of Black Holes.

(iii) Lecture Notes by Prof. Emanuele Berti at the summer school at ICTS (2016). [Black Hole Perturbation Theory](https://www.scribd.com/document/443855884/berteri-black-hole-perturbation-theory#).

have written that the energy of the field has been increased in this case (and hence the mass and rotation of the black-hole has been decreased)?

Comment: When you studied classical electromagnetism, did you learn the formula for the energy density of a classical electromagnetic field?

Comment: I did. But that was a classical formulation! I've understood that here 'energy is increased' is used to mean that the amplitude of the wave is increasing. But if I consider the quantum picture (or if I treat the EM field as photon), then the change in frequency is required to change its energy (as $E = \hbar\omega$). So...

Comment: All of the calculations you mention are of the scattering of a *classical* EM wave by a black hole; they’re not doing quantum gravity. In any case, if you want to imagine the classical EM wave as consisting of photons, its energy doesn’t depend only on the frequency; it depends also on how many photons there are (which is related to the wave amplitude).

Comment: Okay, I got it.

Comment: The quantum picture would be that more photons come out than you send in, all of the same frequency.

Comment: @Ghoster Can you refer some source where I can find the quantum treatment, that you're stating about.

Comment: Sorry, I haven’t seen such a calculation (but that doesn’t mean one doesn’t exist). My comment was my assumption about how it would have to work in a quantum treatment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141897/discussion-between-sch-and-ghoster).